# Registration Form Redirecting to Success Page on Load

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am piecing PHP scripts together to learn how to build a registration form. The form is supposed to take the info, check for empty fields, then insert into the db, if successful shoot out an email and then redirect to the success page.

With the code below it seems to think on page load that something has been entered into the db and then redirects immediately to the success page on page load. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 if(empty($_POST["first_name"]))
 {
   $first_name_err = "<p>What is your first name?</p>";
 }
 if(empty($_POST["last_name"]))
 {
   $last_name_err = "<p>What is your last name?</p>";
 }
 //checks email
 if(empty($_POST["email"]))
 {
   $email_err = "<p>What is your email address?</p>";
 }
 if(empty($_POST["phone"]))
 {
   $phone_err = "<p>What is your phone number?</p>";
 }
  if(empty($_POST["password"]))
 {
   $pass_err = "<p>Please enter your password</p>";
 }

}

require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

// Get values from form
$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);    
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);


// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO dontblame (first_name, last_name, email, phone, password, reg_date)
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone', SHA1('$password'), NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
 //Send to Success Page
header('Location: ../thankyou.php?first_name=' . htmlentities($first_name));
    }
 else {
  echo "ERROR there was a problem with the registration form. Please try again.";
    } 
    // close mysql
    mysql_close();

if(IsInjected($email))
{
    echo "Please don't SPAM.";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'hello@dontblame.co';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Welcome to Jon's First Registration Form";
$email_body = "Hi, $first_name,\n".
    "\n Welcome to Jon's First Registration Form! Below is your login information: \n\n Username: $email \n Password: $password \r\n".

$to = "$email";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_from \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str){
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your first `if` closes too soon, it should span all the code that deals with the db insert, that will solve it right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several bugs:

**1)** The first `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` shall span everything, or better,

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') { ...redirect somewhere...}
```

EDIT: The difference is that your version requires you to remember "all the way down" the condition above. If you follow the "exit early" idea, the code you read WILL be executed once you get there. That makes it easier to read and maintain. (There are other factors like reducing the [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), but ignore that for now.)

**2)** The sql query will always work and return a result, hence there is no controll if everything was entered. The reason is that $email can be empty if no $_POST['email'] is given

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

so the query will simply insert an empty email adress without error. (Unless you set that field unique, but that is another story.)

EDIT: If you use PhpMyAdmin (you certanly should unless you know MySQL in and out), go to the structure of the table, and add an index of type unique (symbolized by the letter u). Alternatively you can scroll down till "indeces", and click add index. (The syntax is basicly an ALTER TABLE, but gor for the graphicalinterface for now).

**3)** If the isInjected() function returns true, your script will exit with a "don´t spam" message. How ever, you already set a Location-header, so that the don´t spam will never be seen.

Comment: 1. Thanks Zsolt. This fixed it. Can you explain the difference between the 2 if statement? 2. What is the best way to make sure it is unique and doesn't already exist in the db?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. **I edited my answer accordingly.** (Please remember to upvote and accept helpful answers, to mark them for fellow developers with the same question.)

Comment: 1. When I switched the first if statement it broke everything again.  <br /> 2. Thank you. I changed that in PHPMyAdmin (it won't let me upvote)

Comment: Everything seems to be working except if I hit submit with nothing filled out, I get the errors, but it is still inserting a blank email into the db...

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing needs wrapping in the post check:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

You only have the validation code wrapped in that. Until you do that, it will always insert a blank row on load because there is no condition.

Also, your validation code appears to be incomplete. It creates a variable `$pass_err` with an error message but then you never do anything with it.

You need to move your email send code so that it executes before the redirect. Currently it executes after the redirect which is a problem because the execution may not always reach that point (as soon as the browser receives the redirect header, it will disconnect from the server and that will in turn stop the PHP execution).

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to have fixed it! In regards to the errors I just have them printing under the form fields if they are blank. Should I be doing something different?

Comment: @JonTaggart yes, you need to wrap the processing code in another check, which will prevent inserting blank rows to the database, if the the input is not valid.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for the secondary check? Right now if you click submit on the form, it displays the errors but also throws in a new insert with a blank email.

Comment: What is happening now is that if I click submit I get the appropriate errors, but it still inserts a blank email into the db. I have been searching and haven't found a solution to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you get to your `header()`  function in your code, you automatically go to your success page.

```
header('Location: ../thankyou.php?first_name=' . htmlentities($first_name));
```

That code tell php to go straight to your thankyou.php page and exit the rest of the code.
an easy solution is to check if you have submitted the form before you redirect.

Good Luck

Edit:

If your problem is with the email not being sent out, you need to put the email send before your header. Header exits the code as soon at it reaches that line assuming the headers have not already been send. for more info on here the header function see [phps header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)